# Pizza Ordering Program

Tags: java, methods, constructor

```
public class PizzaEx {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   char letter;
   String input;
   int sizeD;
   int pizzaCount=1;
   Pizza pieOne;

   do{
       sizeD = getValidSize();
       input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of topping do you wish to order? " +
                                                 "\n Green Pepper" +
                                                 "\n Mushroom"+
                                                 "\n Sausage"+
                                                 "\n Pepperoni"+
                                                 "\n Plain");

       pieOne = new Pizza(sizeD, input);
       System.out.println(pieOne);
       System.out.println("The Number of pizzas made are " + pieOne.getPizzaCount() +"."+"\n");
       input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Do you wish to continue?\n "+
                                                 "'y' or 'Y' for YES\n"+
                                                 "'n' or 'N' for NO\n");
       letter = input.charAt(0);

           pizzaCount = pizzaCount +1;
   }
   while (letter == 'Y'|| letter == 'y');

   System.exit(0);
}

private static int getValidSize()
{
    int d;
    String input;
    do{
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What size of pizza do you wish to order? "+
                                                  "\n 9 inch"+
                                                  "\n 12 inch"+
                                                  "\n 16 inch");
        d = Integer.parseInt(input);
    } while (!(d==9 || d==12 || d==16));
    return d;
}
```

so the above is my main class

```
public class Pizza {



    private int diameter;
    private int numOfPizza;
    private double price;
    private String tops;

Pizza(int sizeD, String input) {
    diameter = sizeD;
    tops = input;

}

public int getDiameter(){
    return diameter;
}

/**
 *
 * @param pizzaCount
 * @return
 */
public int getPizzaCount(){
    return numOfPizza;
}
public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
public String getToppings(){
    return tops;
}
public void setDiameter(int sizeD){
    if (sizeD == 9)
        diameter = 9;
    else if ( sizeD == 12)
        diameter = 12;
    else if (sizeD == 15)
        diameter = 15;
    else
        diameter = 0;
    }    
public void setPizzaCount(int pizzaCount){
    numOfPizza = pizzaCount;
}
public void setPrice(double total){
    price = total;
}
public void setToppings(String input){
    if ("green pepper".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
        tops = "Green Pepper";
    else if ("mushroom".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
        tops = "Mushroom";
    else if ("sausage".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
        tops = "Sausage";
    else if ("pepperoni".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
        tops = "Pepperoni";
    else 
        tops = "Plain";
}
private double calculatePrice(int sizeD, String input){
    double total;
    if (sizeD == 9 && (tops).equalsIgnoreCase("plain")) 
        total = 5.95;
    else if (sizeD == 9)
        total = 6.95;
    else if (sizeD == 12  && (tops).equalsIgnoreCase("plain") )
        total = 7.95;
    else if (sizeD == 12)
        total = 8.95;
    else if (sizeD == 16 && (tops).equalsIgnoreCase("plain"))
        total = 9.95;
    else if (sizeD == 16)
        total = 10.95;
    else 
        total = 0.0;

    return total;
}
public String toString(){
    String pizzaString ="You have ordered a "+diameter + " inch pizza with "+tops +" toppings and a price of $"+ calculatePrice(diameter, tops);
    return pizzaString;
}
```

When I do the the print out, it keeps saying amount of pizza made are = 0 even though I set `pizzaCount = 1`. Also when it ask for topping, if I type any String besides the valid topping choices `{"green peppers", "mushroom", "sausage", "pepperoni", "plain"}` it will count the String as a topping and will be charged for the topping when it should be anything that is not `{"green peppers", "mushroom", "sausage", "pepperoni"}` should be considered `"plain"`

This is not a homework assignment or test problem. It was some extra practice handed out by my professor and is not for a grade. I just want some help to clarify why the String tops is not being assigned the value that the method `setToppings()` is calling to do.

Comment: You set pizzaCount in the PizzaEx main method equals to 1.  But you print out pieOne.getPizzaCount().  This draws from numOfPizza from the Pizza class which never get's set.

Comment: so if i pick a 9inch pizza with a non-valid topping like " olives" // the print out will be You have ordered a 9 inch pizza with olives toppings and a price of $6.95  when it should be edited to change "olives" to "plain" because olives is not a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you always get `0` with `getNumOfPizza()` is because you never increment `int numOfPizza`, you only increment `pizzaCount` in `main`.

As for the `topping`, the reason why you charge for toppings even if you enter an invalid String, is because of your logic in `calculatePrice`, where you charge for topping if `!equalsIgnoreCase("plain")`. In other words, anything except for `"plain"` will be considered a topping. In fact, the logic in this method is unnecessarily convoluted, I suggest you simplify some of the `if` statements:

```
private double calculatePrice(int sizeD, String input){
        if(!(tops).equalsIgnoreCase("plain")) {
            total = 1;
        } else {
            total = 0;
        }

        if(sizeD == 9) {
            total += 5.95;
        }

        else if(sizeD == 12) {
            total += 7.95;
        }

        else if(sizeD == 16) {
            total += 9.95;
        }

        return total;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for this logic! didn't even see it as this is probs the best way to do it since all toppings are worth 1$ extra

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Pizza` has a field `private int numOfPizza;` which you are accessing with `pieOne.getPizzaCount()`. Because that field hasn't been *initialized* (and it is a *primitive `int`*) it has a default value of `0`. One possible fix,

```
private int numOfPizza = 1;
```

Be sure that you are considering which *count* you are interested in; the local `count` or the `Pizza` count. Once that is fixed, you should also change

```
pizzaCount = pizzaCount +1;
```

to something like

```
pizzaCount += pieOne.getPizzaCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following constructor:

```
Pizza(int sizeD, String input) {
    diameter = sizeD;
    tops = input;

}
```

As you can see it does not run your logic from `setToppings`.

It also does not set `numOfPizza` and you do not call your `setPizzaCount()` method either. So this class variable remains 0

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two different fields to hold the number of pizzas. The pizza class should only hold data about the individual pizzas and the other class should hold the data about the amount of pizzas. In your main class you initialize pizzaCount to 1, but then try getting the number from the pizza numOfPizza field.

**Edit** Also, on a separate note, your main class has too much going on in there. You should abstract some stuff out and put it in methods.

Comment: I would change the main class but it's how the main class was written and given to me as part of the example so trying to keep it as vanilla as possible

Answer (score 0):

**When you print:**

```
System.out.println("The Number of pizzas made are " + pieOne.getPizzaCount() +"."+"\n");
```

you are accessing **pieOne**. Lets check initialization:

```
Pizza pieOne = new Pizza(sizeD, input);
```

where `sizeD` stores the pizza size (like 9) and `input` stores a String.

The function `pieOne.getPizzaCount()` checks inside `pieOne` and returns `numOfPizza`;

```
public int getPizzaCount(){
    return numOfPizza;
}
```

But since you never actually stored that value inside the object, it will return zero!

You net to call `setPizzaCount()` before printing anything.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the String for toppings is coming back as whatever the user types every time is because the setToppings() method is declared but never called. You need to call it on the "tops" variable for it to work. As it is, the program skips the method altogether.

Here is one way you could call the method in your program:

```
public String toString()
{
    //method call
    setToppings(tops);
    String pizzaString = "You have ordered a " + diameter + " inch pizza with " + tops + " toppings and a price of $" + calculatePrice(diameter, tops);
    return pizzaString;
}
```

}

The problem with your number of pizzas is the same situation. The setPizzaCount() method had never been called, therefore numOfPizza was never set. Since int variables automatically default to 0 if they are not instantiated, you get a value of 0 every time. Also, you may want to consider using the increment (++) operator when you add one to the number of pizzas. It exists to help make your code easier for you to write and for others to understand when incrementing numbers.

Here's an example:

```
do
    {
        sizeD = getValidSize();
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of topping do you wish to order? " +
                "\n Green Pepper" +
                "\n Mushroom" +
                "\n Sausage" +
                "\n Pepperoni" +
                "\n Plain");
        pieOne = new Pizza(sizeD, input);
        //method call
        pieOne.setPizzaCount(pizzaCount);
        System.out.println(pieOne);
        System.out.println("The Number of pizzas made are " + pieOne.getPizzaCount() + "." + "\n");
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Do you wish to continue?\n " +
                "'y' or 'Y' for YES\n" +
                "'n' or 'N' for NO\n");
        letter = input.charAt(0);
        pizzaCount++;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your example. I worked a different way but I like this better

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If it was beneficial to you, an up vote would be much appreciated.